# 18 or 36 VDC to 24 VAC?

Tags: hvac

i have a couple 18V makita powertool batteries that i'd like to be able to use in a blackout to "turn on" my boiler. the boiler is natural gas with a solenoid valve that opens with 24VAC.

does any know of a slick way (using out of the box stuff ideally) to convert 18VDC (or 36VDC for 2 batteries in series) to 24VAC?

my current thought is this:

[18VDC battery] --> [18VDC to 12VDC stepdown converter] --> [12VDC to 120VAC inverter] --> [120VAC to 24VAC transformer] --> [solenoid valve]

haven't tried it yet. it just seems a little more cumbersome necessary. e.g. i haven't seen an 18VDC to 120VAC inverter that would let me eliminate the converter.

maybe the makita charger itself can be used as an inverter? i don't know enough electrical to know if that's possible.

thanks

Comment: Most "boilers" are in fact hot-water heaters which need pumps to circulate hot (not boiling) water.  Inspect the furnace thoroughly and I bet you'll find other essential electrical gear.  *However if the solenoid valve is in fact the only electrical load*, I'm guessing this boiler is also made in a version that uses a thermocouple and millivolt thermostat.  Ask the manufacturer what it would take to convert, because that would be 100% electricity free. A Nest or other 24V 'stat can be used in parallel with the millivolt 'stat (it fires if either one calls for heat).

Comment: What make and model is your boiler?

Comment: Go buy a small generator, and save yourself a headache. Any thing can be done but is it worth the time and cost?

Comment: my heat is old school steam radiators, so the gas valve is the only necessary load (well, there's also a low water cutoff and an exhaust damper i can open manually). it's a utica but i don't have model # in front of me.

i have a "portable" generator. i've used it to run the heat, but it's just a little too un-portable to lug around and setup unless it's an extended outage. so this is just an idea to run heat only. i have everything but the converter (<$10). and the valve only draws several mA, so i think the batteries could run the heat for a while.

Comment: Can you read the gas valve voltage, Is it 24 volts? Also to be safe you would have to make sure all the safety and operating controls are being used and in the electricity circuit. If they would be out of the circuit and not be protecting the boiler then I would not use the battery or any other makeshift arrangement. It would not be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If your boiler is truly a steam system with no return pumps, or any other device using electricity, you could convert to a thermopile  or pilot generator and have a system that uses no outside power. It would not be cheap but it can be done. The thermostat, gas valve and all other parts  and devices in the circuit  would have to be replaced with parts  compatible with a pilot generator. This would allow you to go off the grid so to speak. I would have an HVAC company do the work just to be safe. Also screwing around with a steam boiler or other heating devices without extensive knowledge could get you to an early grave. All these devices are extremely dangerous if you don't know what you are doing and even sometimes when you know what you are doing.